# How to solve the differential equation $A(x)y''+A'(x)y'+ay=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have problems solving an equation and I have to solve a second order diferential eacution first but a don't remember how to deal with that kind of equations. Is this:

$$A(x)y''+A'(x)y'+ay=0$$

where

$A(x)=ce^{-\frac{k}{t(x)}}$, $c,k>0$,

$A'(x)=ce^{-\frac{k}{t(x)}}\frac{k}{t(x)^2}t'(x)$,

and $a>0.$

Comment: Without more information on $a_i(x)$, you cannot say much about the possibility of this equation having an explicit solution. In other words: in general, you *cannot* express a solution $y(x)$ in terms of the coefficient functions $a_i(x)$ in some general, prescribed way. If you would share the explicit form of these $a_i(x)$ though, there might be people able to help you.